# how to use multiple or & and condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need the comp_gid as compulsory remaining fields like holder1_name,holder1_fh_name,holder1_pan_no may contain values or it will be null

```
SELECT * 
FROM sta.sta_trn_tfolio 
where (holder1_name='AMAR' or holder1_fh_name='' or holder1_pan_no='') 
AND comp_gid='1' ;
```

but i am getting only comp_gid condition. Help me if anybody knows

Comment: show the table structure and data

Answer (score 0):

You should add check on NULL:

```
 SELECT * FROM sta.sta_trn_tfolio 
 where 
    (holder1_name IS NULL OR 
     holder1_fh_name IS NULL OR 
     holder1_pan_no IS NULL OR 
     holder1_name='AMAR' or 
     holder1_fh_name='' or 
     holder1_pan_no='')     
    AND comp_gid='1' ;
```

Comment: sorry, wasn't attentive enough (updated the answer), but the point is the same: you should check nullable values on null additionally. NULL = <<anything>> is false